# NestJS getting wrong route

Tags: routes, sequelize.js, nestjs, backend

I have these two similar routes:

```
  @Get('/name/exact')
  findByName(@Query() query: { supplierID: string; name: string }) {
    console.log('3')
    return this.supplierProductService.findByName(query);
  }

  @Get('/name/like')
  findByLikeName(@Query() query: { supplierID: string; name: string }) {
    console.log('4')
    return this.supplierProductService.findByLikeName(query);
  }
```

Whenever i call the first one from my frontend the bottom one is actually executed, any idea why this happens?

Comment: Have you tested with `postman` or `curl`?

Comment: Showing what you call here would be really useful. And probably the full controller. Do you have any middleware or interceptors going on too?